# How to create a new directory using pathlib in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, pathlib

I am attempting to create a new directory using Python using the pathlib library.  Unfortunately I seem to be having some issues with doing so.  I have a base directory that has already been created and a directory beneath this that I need to create, the name of which has been extracted from a config.txt text file previously and added to a variable.  This variable is a name e.g. 'DAVE', or 'DAVE-C' and is a string. Unfortunately, i am getting an error message when i run my code.

My code is as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path

DESTINATION_LOC_DEFAULT = Path('C:\work')
NAME = Path(new_dir)

DEST_DIR = DESTINATION_LOC_DEFAULT / new_dir
print(DEST_DIR)

Path(DEST_DIR).mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)
```

The print statement is this:
C:\work<name from config file>

But, i also get an error message:

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\work\name from config file\n'

However, if i replace the NAME variable with this:

`NAME = Path('DAVE')`

it works.
I am a bit confused as to why the second option works, where i am explicitly stating the name of the last folder, and the first doesn't work where i am using a string variable that has been converted to a path object.  Looking at the error message, there appears to be a '\n' at the end, i suspect this has something to do with it, but i'm not sure.  Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You need to strip the newline character off of the end of the lines you read from your config file.

Answer (score 0):

To complete jasonharper's answer: according to your OS and the method you use to read your config file content, you can indeed end up with a '\n' character that you need to strip, using `new_dir = new_dir.strip()` .

More generally, I'd suggest that your config file be in another format than `.txt`, to avoid this problem.

So if you can edit this file, a `config.json` or a `config.py` file may be more appropriate to save your variable.

Other possibility: a `.env` file (here `.env` is not a suffix but the conventional name of the file) used in conjunction with [dotenv module](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/).

Comment: That's exactly it!!!!!  Thank you.  The config file comes as a text file, so, i'll make a recommendation to change that.  Thanks for the help